# Set Admin Home to Forbidden without Correct Login Credentials

Tags: asp.net

I am making a website and i want Admin Home/User Home Page to Be Forbidden without Verifying with Correct Login Credentials. But How i Can.

```
    protected void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckFields())
        {
            user.Employee_ID = txtEID.Text;
            user.Employee_Password = txtEPassword.Text;
            user.Role = ddlRole.SelectedItem.ToString();

            if (uc.Login(user)==true && user.Role=="Admin")
            {
                Session["userID"] = user.Employee_ID;
                Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Admin.aspx");
            }
            else if (uc.Login(user) == true && user.Role == "Team Admin")
            {
                Session["userID"] = user.Employee_ID;
                Response.Redirect("TeamAdmin.aspx");
            }
            else if (uc.Login(user) == true && user.Role == "Team Admin")
            {
                Session["userID"] = user.Employee_ID;
                Response.Redirect("TeamMember.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

upto here it is working fine. but when i set the path directly to admin page (http://mysite.com/Admin/Admin.aspx) of the site it is showing all the contents of the admin page. i need admin page to b forbidden without verifying correct login credentials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a web.config file in the Admin directory with this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If you're using some form of asp.net authentication it will deny any user that is not authenticated.

Comment: It relates to the authentication scheme you're using.  So if you use forms authentication you will have some database of users or roles, if you use windows authentication it will be active directory or computer local users / groups (groups == roles in this sense).  It's all based on how you set up your users, and windows authentication is definitely the easiest if this is on a corporate intranet or something.  Look at your parent web.config and see what you have in the authentication section.  Possibly research the types of authentication to figure out what you want to use.

Comment: Also, you may be reinventing the wheel on your login control.  ASP.NET has this functionality built in, it'll just take some googling to properly leverage it.

Comment: Hey no problem, that's why I'm here :).  Best of luck.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36814/discussion-between-rummykhan-and-subterfuge)

Comment: now when i login through my login panel it is redirecting back to my login page..

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement authorization (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx).

If your admin page is in a separate folder that only administrators should have access to, then you can put a web.config file in that folder with an authorization section as described in the link above.  You could set this authorization section to restrict access to only users who are members of the Admin role.  In order for this to work properly, you must be using ASP.Net security and authorization.

Alternatively, in the Page_Load() method of the Admin.aspx page, you could put code to check that the user is a member of the Admins role.  If they are not, redirect them to another page.

I prefer configuring page level authorization in the .config files because it keeps it in one place and allow it to be easily updated in the future.

Comment: thanx for your solution bro.. im checing it